# MYSQL Deadlock with Queue Table

Tags: mysql

I have a queue table that has a list of jobs that need to process. Records are inserted by a PHP process and then I have up to 10 node.js jobs checking that table to see if the record can be completed yet. I'm using the following UPDATE with Select to add the jobId and change the status of that row so that it can be processed. (I'm doing the update so that multiple threads are not checking the same row at the same time, and can continue processing by looking up the jobId and status later in script)  I'm running in to deadlocks when running the node.js threads. (The PHP server is also getting deadlocks if it tries to update any rows in the queue table while the node.js scripts are running)

This is my update/select:

```
UPDATE queue SET status='pending', jobID = 1
   WHERE sharequeueid IN (
        SELECT sharequeueid FROM (
             SELECT sharequeueid FROM queue 
             WHERE status = "waiting"
             ORDER BY lastcheck DESC  
             LIMIT 1
         ) tmp
   )
```

I have an index containing status and lastcheck

Create Table Statement:

```
   CREATE TABLE `queue` (
  `sharequeueid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eventid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shared` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastcheck` datetime NOT NULL,
  `shareerror` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `jobId` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any thoughts on how to stop the deadlock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be reduced to

> ```
> create table queue (sharequeueid bigint,status char(10),jobID  INT, lastcheck  datetime)
> ```

> 

> ```
> insert into queue vALUES(1,'waiting',0,now()),(2,'waiting',0,now()),(3,'waiting',0,now()),(4,'waiting',0,now());
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE queue SET status='pending', jobID = 1 WHERE status='waiting' ORDER BY lastcheck LIMIT 1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM queue
> ```
>
> ```
> sharequeueid | status  | jobID | lastcheck          
> -----------: | :------ | ----: | :------------------
>            1 | pending |     1 | 2020-06-25 19:39:20
>            2 | waiting |     0 | 2020-06-25 19:39:20
>            3 | waiting |     0 | 2020-06-25 19:39:20
>            4 | waiting |     0 | 2020-06-25 19:39:20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80e1f9bc19ac0d7b9bc6374cfbecd97f)*

Comment: This results in "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'queue' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: you changed your query

Comment: Sorry I had a typo added. Create table added to post

Comment: i changed my answer now accourding to your changes

Comment: That seems to have helped. I'm not getting the deadlocks anymore